# Non-English text shown as ???? in Android Textview

Tags: android, textview

Am developing an android application which has to display different languages like

```
1.Kannada,
2.English,
3.Hindi,
4.Telugu,
5.Tamil
```

In Text View, the data is stored in `database`. am able to retrieve and view only English if I select any other language it is showing question marks(??????) like this **AND** am Fetching through **PHP** is need to use any libraries? or any other solutions. can any one help me to do this.

```
<?php

  $con=  mysqli_connect("localhost","root","oracle","DBname") ;

   $id=$_REQUEST['id'];

    $SelectQuery="select * from language where id='$id' ";

    $result=mysqli_query($con,$SelectQuery) or die(mysqli_error());


    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    echo $row['langType'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set custom Typeface for your textview for other language (non-english lang)
Just like

```
  Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/MyFont.ttf")
  txtview.setTypeface(tf);
```

Your custom font (.ttf file) must be in //Assets/fonts Folder..
i hope this may help you ..

Also you can download custom fonts from [this link](http://hindi-fonts.com/)

Comment: cannot place in assets folder.

Comment: copy your fontname.ttf file in fonts folder inside assets folder then try to execute above code...its working surly..why you cant get it :(